# Human readable system memory reading from CLI?

Tags: memory, system-information

On OS X, I get a nice *human readable* system memory reading like so:

```
printf -v system_memory \
          "$(system_profiler SPHardwareDataType \
             | awk -F ': ' '/^ +Memory: /{print $2}')"
echo "$system_memory"
```

prints out the friendly:

```
4 GB
```

Although this on Linux is correct:

```
lshw -class memory
```

it outputs:

```
size: 4096MiB
```

I need to painfully parse it and try to make it into a string as nice as the one above.

Am I using the wrong command?

Comment: "I need to painfully parse it"... That big ugly thing for osx isn't painful? :-)

Comment: @Patrick: I dislike OS X when comparing it to Linux!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If that's all you need, just use `free`:

```
$ free -h | gawk  '/Mem:/{print $2}'
7.8G
```

`free` returns memory info, the `-h` switch tells it to print in human readable format.

Comment: I did not know `free` had a (nice) `-h` switch. Thanks. Very interesting how `free` deems `4.0G` (which is what I get) more human friendly than `4 GB`. "Mum, I'm hungry, I'd like 1.0 apple, please." If this is the best we have on Linux, I should probably just parse the number out and replace `G` with `GB` myself.. Very rarely do we see HDDs, for example, advertised as "320G" rather than "320 GB". __:(__

Comment: @Robottinosino, HDD sizes are expressed in GB (10^9 bytes), while memory is generally expressed in GiB (2^30 bytes), 4.0G gives you an idea of the precision. With 4GB, you don't know if it's exactly 4GB (or 4GiB?) or 4.4GB rounded down to 4 or 3.6G rounded up to 4.

Comment: @Robottinosino If you want to round it off to a more human-readable number and add `GB`, try `free -h | gawk  '/Mem:/{print $2}' | rev | cut -c 2- | rev | xargs printf "%.*fGB\n" 0`

Answer (score 3):

On Linux,

```
read x memtotal x < /proc/meminfo
```

Would store the total mem amount in `$memory` in number of kiB. That's the amount of memory available to Linux, the same as reported by `free`.

If you want the installed RAM, you could do things like:

```
awk '{s+=$0};END{print s}' /sys/bus/mc*/devices/dimm*/size
```

To get the size in MiBs. Or

```
awk '{s+=$0};END{printf "%.2gG\n", s/1024}' /sys/bus/mc*/devices/dimm*/size
```

If you want the size in GiB.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is using *free* command

```
free -gh
```

Comment: You need to parse that as well.